# All norm is strictly convex function?

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, convex-analysis, normed-spaces, nonlinear-optimization

I know all norms are convex functions.

Because $\forall \lambda\in(0,1)$ and for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n $  we have  for all $p$-norm $1\le p\le \infty$ the triangle inequality
$$ \| \lambda x+ (1-\lambda y)\| \le \| \lambda x\| +\|(1-\lambda) y\|  = 
| \lambda |\|x\| +(1-\lambda) \|y\|. $$

Do we have strict inequality for all norm?

Comment: It is not completely clear what you mean. The triangle inequality is only generally true with $\le$ and not with $<$, e.g. because $\|x+0\| <\|x\|+\|0\|$ would be wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  The $1$-norm and $\infty$-norm are not strictly convex.  Their unit balls are polyhedra, and if you pick $x$ and $y$ to be distinct points on the same face, their convex combinations will be on the same face, too.

For example, let $x=(1,1)$ and $y=(1, -1)$.  Then $\|\lambda x+(1-\lambda) y\|_\infty=1$ for all $\lambda\in[0,1]$. Another:  let $x=(1,0)$ and $y=(0,1).$ Then $\|\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y\|_1 =1 $ for all $\lambda\in[0,1]$.

Comment: hello  is there any counter example?

Comment: thanks ;-) that's very good example.